# Why Origin http header is being sent with XHR to same origin in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

In a Chrome extension, my content script is initiating XHR to the same origin. For example, content script is for `https://example.com`, and the content-script of that extension is initiating XHR (GET) to `https://example.com/api/status`.

It was working fine but recently a small percentage of users (less than 1%) has reported that the extensions doesn't work for them. When I investigated, I found that on the computers where it doesn't work, Chrome sends `Origin` header in GET XHR request. This header is not present on computers where the extension works.

```
Origin: chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It makes me wonder that Chrome is treating this XHR as cross origin request. If I uninstall the Chrome completely and install again, the problem goes away. Please can you suggest why that might happen or perhaps how to diagnose the issue?

Comment: It's a bug which got fixed in 75+, see https://crbug.com/940068.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. But this issue has also been reported by one Edge Chromium user (version 76). I tried with network-service flag (chrome://flags/#network-service) as suggested by someone in https://crbug.com/940068 thread and disabling this flag fixes the issue.

Comment: Edge Chromium is a totally separate thing, right now it's no more than an experimental fork.